# wait and notify problem

Tags: java, multithreading, jdialog

When I am using the `wait()` method in the following code its throwing the following Exeption

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

The code is as follows:

```
private void newMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        newFileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        int returnVal = newFileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            filename = newFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            JFrame mainFrame = NetSimApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
            networktype = new NetType(mainFrame);
            networktype.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
            NetSimApp.getApplication().show(networktype);
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(NetSimView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if (!NetType.validip) {
                statusTextArea.append("File not created:Select Network Type.\n");
            }
            newNodeMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
             newNodeMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
            statusTextArea.append("File not created:Access cancelled by user.\n");
        }
    }
```

Actually I am calling the object of a jDialog class and i want that the dialog object should complete first and then it should notify the above given code. I've already specified notify() in that class. Can anyone tell me whats the problem and its solution.  -Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `wait` method needs to be enclosed in a `synchronized` method or a `lock` block, with the object being locked on the object you want to wait upon.

In your case, you should make the method `synchronized`, which is equivalent to calling `lock (this)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start `wait` by acquiring synchronization on the wait variable, e.g.

```
synchronized( this )
{
    this.wait( );
}
```

Please read the javadoc for [wait](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) carefully and follow it to the letter, otherwise you'll be up to nasty surprises.

Comment: for notfy() also I have to do the same thing??

Answer (score 0):

1. synchronized block of code where "wait()" is
2. don't "notify" Thread, "notify" runnable, Thread is a Control class for runnable
   and Thread wraps notify/notifyAll/wait with monitor class
3. try using interupt and throw a "non-error" throwable to pause/resume
   thread.
4. use producent/consumer approach
5. use fork/join approach
6. use Thread pool for pausing and resuming thread (pause - kill
   runnable, resume - pool runnable)

Any of these approaches would eliminate your problem, the problem itself is that you try to notify already notified thread, its same problem like starting already started thread. It will throw a IllegalMonitorStateException.

Thread is a horribly written solution to Process but its not so hard to manage.

Comment: Since January I am working on answer to "Thread problem" I'm half way throught.

The "problem" is when you want to rewrite something critical like Thread, you must inject it into JVM in Runtime (JX16 and SecurityManager class would not accept it otherwise and native classes are signed in JVM so you cannot call these specific native classes without causing security error).

My "Thread" don't need guard block, locks, semaphors and monitors it uses WeakReferences Map to monitor its references and usage not Stack like thread (so there are more "current thread" than one)... half way throught.